# Single-width "10" for card game presentation

Tags: characters, layout

I play and teach bridge, and the shape of hands is very important.  For instance:

```
KJ854
Q9842
8
A3
```

is easy to recognize as equal-length majors (top two rows).  But then there's the ten.

Various style guides have options for this card; all of which are designed to minimize the "shape" problem.  Either use spaces:

```
K J 10 8 5
Q 9 8 4 2
8
A 10
```

(but that doesn't work completely - the spades still look longer than the hearts, just not quite as bad as KJ1085 Q9842)
or use "T" for ten:

```
KJT85
Q9842
8
AT
```

(but the card has "10" on it, not "T", and it's hard to read!)

In unicode there are several characters that are single-character-width 10, but never naked (10-in-circle, 10-as-playing-card, 10-full-stop, ...)  Is there a native (i.e. normal font) or simple way in LaTeX to get a single-width "10" element?

Comment: A *very* cheap-and-dirty way would be to use some non-Latin letter visually similar to “10”, e.g. the Cyrillic Ю: `AJЮ83`.

Comment: There is the [onedown](https://ctan.org/pkg/onedown?lang=en) package designed for typesetting bridge hands and play. It requires you to enter `T` for 10, but it displays `10` with extra kerning so that the two characters sit closer together. If you google there are also quite a few other bridge typsetting packages floating around that are not on CTAN.

Comment: Had not seen this.  I was looking at tweaking the https://taigabridge.net/latex/index.htm grbbridge package (which does everything I want, I know the writer, and use his other bridge package already, but didn't handle kerned 10).  Now I have more options.  Thank you all.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You can use

`\makebox[2em]{1}...\makebox[2em]{9}...\makebox[2em]{10}...\makebox[2em]{K}`

and they will all be 2em wide, choose whatever width works best for the font you are using.

Here are three versions, a spacy version with 2em width and 10 normally spaced and a tighter version using 1em spacing and 10 squeezed slightly and a ver y tight version.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}

\begin{document}

\makebox[2em]{1}\makebox[2em]{9}\makebox[2em]{10}\makebox[2em]{K}

\makebox[2em]{10}\makebox[2em]{J}\makebox[2em]{Q}\makebox[2em]{K}


\bigskip


\makebox[1em]{1}\makebox[1em]{9}\makebox[1em]{1\kern-.1em0}\makebox[1em]{K}

\makebox[1em]{1\kern-.1em0}\makebox[1em]{J}\makebox[1em]{Q}\makebox[1em]{K}


\bigskip


\makebox[.8em]{1}\makebox[.8em]{9}\makebox[.8em]{1\kern-.16em0}\makebox[.8em]{K}

\makebox[.8em]{1\kern-.16em0}\makebox[.8em]{J}\makebox[.8em]{Q}\makebox[.8em]{K}

\end{document}
```

---

Once you have decided the tweaks you want, you can abstract that into a command, something like

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}

\def\tmpx{10}
\newcommand\Cd[1]{%
  \makebox[.8em]{\def\tmp{#1}%
   \ifx\tmp\tmpx
     \kern-.05em1\kern-.12em0%  10
   \else
    #1% not 10
   \fi}}

\begin{document}

\Cd{1}\Cd{9}\Cd{10}\Cd{K}

\Cd{10}\Cd{J}\Cd{Q}\Cd{K}

\end{document}
```

You could also test for other letters, Q could perhaps have a slight adjustment to the left as well.

Comment: I'll see how this works when embedded in full hands.  I think this will work very well, given the other issue is spacing (all hands have 13 cards in 4 suits, but might be 5512 like my example, or 3433, or 1192).  I see the same \kern game that Oni suggested here as well; I think a combination of the two (make a newcommand \T and set cards in \makebox-es in a \hand macro) will solve my problem nicely.  Will wait a bit before accepting an answer.

Comment: @Mycroft yes either way you'd want a macro that abstracts away any tweaks that you decide, you don't want to be puttting makebox[1.23457em explicitly all over the document.

Comment: @Mycroft note it isn't just 10 that I have forced here, but JQK are also forced to the same width as are the digits. so you'd probably want more than just a`\T` macro, something like `\Cd{1}\Cd{10}\Cd{J}` defined as `\newcommand\Cd[1]{\makebox[1.5em]{\def\tmp{#1}\ifx\tmp\tmpx1\kern-.16em0\else#1\fi}}   \def\tmpx{10}`

Answer (score 6):

One can use `\newcommand{\T}{\kern-.3em 10}`,

If `1` and `0` need to be closer set kerning between them

`\newcommand{\T}{\kern-.2em 1\kern-.2em 0}`

[image: 8, 10, Q]

with `tabbing` each tab can be define what length of spacing you want between numbers.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\setmainfont[Ligatures=TeX]{Liberation Sans}
\setmonofont[Ligatures=TeX]{Liberation Mono}

\usepackage{xcolor}
\newcommand{\Heart}{\textcolor{red}{♥}}
\newcommand{\Spade}{♠}
\newcommand{\Club}{♣}
\newcommand{\Diamant}{\textcolor{red}{♦}}
\newcommand{\T}{\kern-.3em 10}
\begin{document}

{\Huge\ttfamily
\begin{tabbing}
\hspace{15mm} \= \hspace{15mm} \= \hspace{15mm} \= \hspace{15mm} \= \hspace{15mm} \= \kill
\> K \> J \> \T \> 8 \> 5 \\
\> Q \> 9 \> 8 \> 4 \> 2 \\
\> 8 \\
\> A \> \T \\
\end{tabbing}%
}
\end{document}
```

[image: table]

If one adds `♠♥♦♣` signs with font that support them like `Liberation Mono`

[image: cards]

Comment: The intent is to avoid the spacing (and bridge style sorts for suits, so we would write `\Spade{}KJ\T\85\\\Heart{}Q9842`.  But I'll try the kerning.  This solution would work well for on-the-fly writing; the makebox solution can be loaded into a \hand macro easily for presentation of all 13 well, and a \deal macro for the 4 hands, table, and other relevant information.  Thanks for this!

Answer (score 4):

There is also the playing cards [Unicode block](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Playing_cards_in_Unicode). This is supported by various fonts, such as DejaVu Sans (Linux), Segoe UI Symbol (Windows), Symbola (cross-platform). You can enter the symbols directly or define macros to make it easier to enter a symbol.

MWE (compile with XeLaTeX or LuaLaTeX):

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\setmainfont{DejaVu Sans}
\def\acl{}\def\iiicl{} % macros to make entering easier
\begin{document}
\noindent Example:\\
\\ % or enter symbols directly
\color{red}
\\
\\
\color{black}
\acl\iiicl\\
\end{document}
```

Result:

[image]

Comment: I noticed the question mentions "10 as playing card" as undesired, but it looks sort of nice I guess :)

Comment: Yeah, that's too cute for the style of writing common to bridge.  It's also very hard to read 13 cards.  But still a good answer for other work, potentially poker writing.  Thank you!